# Bean Creation Exception with JBoss 5.1.2

Tags: spring, jboss5.x

I am facing problem while Deploying my app in JBoss 5.1.2 . I am getting the below exception.

```
2013-08-31 22:16:07,968 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (HDScanner) Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class   [com.abc.myapp.cmc.infrastructure.util.CustomPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer] for bean with name 'applicationPropertyConfigurer' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-config/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.abc.myapp.cmc.infrastructure.util.CustomPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1250)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1319)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:885)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4389)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:313)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:145)
at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:122)
at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:297)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1454)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1172)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1193)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1113)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1652)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:938)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:988)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:826)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:556)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:789)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:699)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:409)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.abc.myapp.cmc.infrastructure.util.CustomPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1271)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1242)
... 73 more
```

Here is my bean creation code in applicationContext.xml file. Even if create any bean apart from this i am getting the same Exception mention above.

```
  <bean id="applicationPropertyConfigurer"
    class="com.abc.myapp.cmc.infrastructure.util.CustomPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
</bean>
```

and web.xml contains below details.

```
 <context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The Class for which i am getting exception is available in src folder and it is in classpath of my application. Not sure what i am missing. here are the jar file which i included for building the application in WEB-INF/lib. 
spring-core,
spring-beans, 
spring-context,
spring-context.support,
spring-asm,
spring-expression
and i assume logging related jar not required for the spring because in JBoss Server it will available.

But When i comment out the bean code creation in applicationContext.xml application deployed successfully On the server. Please let me know what exactly i am missing.

Comment: Is that a maven project or an eclipse project? Check the generated WAR file for the class.

Comment: Are you sure there is a class called `com.abc.myapp.cmc.infrastructure.util.CustomPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`.? Also please check the property you have declared. Try including `spring-web` jar in your classpath too.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. it is eclipse project. and it was problem with war file creation in eclipse. i resolved this issue.